# Draggable SVG groups - auto move out of the way when overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, svg, drag-and-drop

I am building a web application for designing houses in Australia, have built most of it, but I'm wanting the room elements to automatically move together when they are close. So far I have been able to get an 2D array of which rooms are touching, but unable to figure out how to move the element closer to each other when the dragging ends. Admittedly I have use a bit if A.I. to assist as I haven't done any work with SVG dragging before.

This is the Javascript code I am using to make the items draggable.
Please let me know if you have a solution or ideas or even examples!
Haven't been able to find much on this

[image]

```
var selectedElement = false;


function makeDraggable(evt) {
  var svg = evt.target;

  svg.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
  svg.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
  svg.addEventListener('mouseup', endDrag);
  svg.addEventListener('mouseleave', endDrag);
  svg.addEventListener('touchstart', startDrag);
  svg.addEventListener('touchmove', drag);
  svg.addEventListener('touchend', endDrag);
  svg.addEventListener('touchleave', endDrag);
  svg.addEventListener('touchcancel', endDrag);
  
  function getMousePosition(evt) {
    var CTM = svg.getScreenCTM();
    if (evt.touches) { evt = evt.touches[0]; }
    return {
      x: (evt.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a,
       y: (evt.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d
    };
  }
  
  var selectedElement, offset, transform;
  
  // Set the size of the grid cell
    const gridSize = 10;
  
    function startDrag(evt) {
      var currentNode = evt.target.parentNode;
    
      while (currentNode && !currentNode.classList.contains('draggable-group')) {
        currentNode = currentNode.parentNode;
      }
    
      if (currentNode) {
        selectedElement = currentNode;
        offset = getMousePosition(evt);
    
        // Get all the transforms currently on this element
        var transforms = selectedElement.transform.baseVal;
    
        // Ensure the first transform is a translate transform
        if (transforms.length === 0 || transforms.getItem(0).type !== SVGTransform.SVG_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE) {
          // Create a transform that translates by (0, 0)
          var translate = svg.createSVGTransform();
          translate.setTranslate(0, 0);
          // Add the translation to the front of the transforms list
          selectedElement.transform.baseVal.insertItemBefore(translate, 0);
        }
    
        // Get initial translation amount
        transform = transforms.getItem(0);
        offset.x -= transform.matrix.e;
        offset.y -= transform.matrix.f;
      }
    }
    
    function drag(evt) {
      if (selectedElement) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var coord = getMousePosition(evt);
        var x = coord.x - offset.x;
        var y = coord.y - offset.y;
    
        // Snap to other groups
        var groups = svg.querySelectorAll('.group');
        groups.forEach(function(group) {
          if (group !== selectedElement) {
            var rect1 = selectedElement.getBBox();
            var rect2 = group.getBBox();
    
            if (isCloseTo(rect1, rect2, snapThreshold)) {
              var dx = rect2.x - rect1.x;
              var dy = rect2.y - rect1.y;
              x = rect2.x + dx;
              y = rect2.y + dy;
            }
          }
        });
    
        // Restrict movement within the boundary
        var lotBoundary = document.getElementById('lot-boundary');
        var lotRect = lotBoundary.getBBox();
        var elementRect = selectedElement.getBBox();
    
        if (x < lotRect.x) {
          x = lotRect.x;
        } else if (x + elementRect.width > lotRect.x + lotRect.width) {
          x = lotRect.x + lotRect.width - elementRect.width;
        }
    
        // Restrict the movement within the lot boundary vertically
        if (y < lotRect.y) {
          y = lotRect.y;
        } else if (y + elementRect.height > lotRect.y + lotRect.height) {
          y = lotRect.y + lotRect.height - elementRect.height;
        }
    
        // Restrict the x movement for the garage element
        if (selectedElement.id === 'garage-standard') {
          var element = document.getElementById("dom-leftboundry");
          var garageOffsetElement = document.getElementById("garage-setbackValue");
          
          if (element && garageOffsetElement) {
            var ownerSVG = element.ownerSVGElement;
            var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            var CTM = ownerSVG.getScreenCTM();
            var garageOffset = parseFloat(garageOffsetElement.value);
            x = (rect.left - CTM.e) / CTM.a + garageOffset; // Set the fixed x-position for the garage element with offset
          }
        }
      
        // Update the translation of the selectedElement
        selectedElement.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${x}, ${y})`);
      }
    }
        
    function endDrag(evt) {
      if (selectedElement) {
        var elementIDs = ['entry-standard', 'garage-standard', 'bathroom-standard', 'wc-standard', 'laundry-standard', 'bedfour-standard', 'bedone-standard', 'ensuite-standard'];
    
        setTimeout(function() {
          var overlappingElements = getOverlappingElements(elementIDs, selectedElement);
    
          if (overlappingElements.length > 0) {
            console.log('The following elements are overlapping:', overlappingElements);
            moveElementsApart(overlappingElements);
          } else {
            console.log('No overlapping elements.');
          }
    
          selectedElement = null;
        }, 100);
      }
    }
    
    function getOverlappingElements(elementIDs, selectedElement) {
      var overlappingElements = [];
    
      const selectedElementID = selectedElement.id;
    
      for (var i = 0; i < elementIDs.length - 1; i++) {
        var element1 = document.getElementById(elementIDs[i]);
    
        for (var j = i + 1; j < elementIDs.length; j++) {
          var element2 = document.getElementById(elementIDs[j]);
    
          if (areElementsOverlapping(element1, element2)) {
            if (elementIDs[i] === selectedElementID) {
              overlappingElements.push([elementIDs[i], elementIDs[j]]);
            } else if (elementIDs[j] === selectedElementID) {
              overlappingElements.push([elementIDs[j], elementIDs[i]]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    
      return overlappingElements;
    }
    
    function areElementsOverlapping(element1, element2) {
      var rect1 = element1.getBoundingClientRect();
      var rect2 = element2.getBoundingClientRect();
    
      return (
        rect1.left < rect2.right &&
        rect1.right > rect2.left &&
        rect1.top < rect2.bottom &&
        rect1.bottom > rect2.top
      );
    }
    
    function moveElementsApart(overlappingElements) {

      //have the room elements move into place

    }
    
    
    
    
}
```